# Interesting equation with fractions

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

Find distinct positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ such that

$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-\frac{1}{d} = \frac{1}{a} \cdot \frac{1}{b} \cdot \frac{1}{c} \cdot\left( -\frac{1}{d}\right)$$

No calculators or computers allowed.

Comment: Associates to equations of theoretical physics.

Comment: @z100 ooh please tell us more

Comment: @Dmitriy Kamenetsky  left side reminds me of some Minkowski space equations (with a space-time as a model, where time coordinate has different sign  to  3 space coordinates).  BTW, OP's equation can be simplified to  D-(A+B+C)=ABCD along the condition A,B,C,D are all inverse naturals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These work

> a=7, b=3, c=2, d= 1

Method used

> First put both sides of the equation over a common denominator, namely abcd.

This gives

> bcd+acd+abd-abc=-1

Notice that

> if d is very large, then this will probably not work, so try d=1

This gives

> bc+ac+ab-abc = -1

Try

> c=2 to keep the numbers small

This gives

> 2b+2a+ab-2ab = -1

Try

> b=3 to keep the numbers small

This gives

> 6+2a+3a-6a = -1

Solving gives

> -a = -7   or  a=7

Answer (score 9):

There are a lot of solutions, e.g.

> $a=bcd+1,b=cd+1,c=d+1,d$
>  $a=bcd+1,b=(cd+1)/2,c=d+2,d$ (for odd d)
>  $a=bcd+1,b=(cd+1)/5,c=d+5,d$ (for d 2mod5 or 3mod5)
>  examples:
>  43  7  3  2
>  119  8  5  3
>  1429 17 12 7